# Allow 2 different subnets to have access to the internet but not each other

Tags: subnet, internet

How would I go about getting say 10.0.1.100 and 10.0.0.100 to both have access to the same internet, but not see each other.

My Topology can change to make this happen.

Currently I have a router/gateway which connects to the internet via LAN cable.
This router at the moment is basically stock setup, apart from a static IP (10.0.0.1), which is what my 10.0.0.x subnet uses to connect to the net... but this doesn't work for the other subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up a firewall rules on the device that routes the two subnets to the Internet.  If your router doesn't support creating rules to do this, then replace it.  Linux appliances are cheap and flexible.

Comment: Router is running DD-WRT so should be able to